# Maxwell Equation + initial data - dissipative or dispersive?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

In Aspects of Symmetry, Coleman says (p. 185)

> ''Most of the simple field theories with which we are familiar have the
>   property that all of their non-singular solutions of finite total energy are dissipative. This is the case for Maxwell's equations, the Klein-Gordon equation, etc.''

However, isn't it the case that the mentioned equations for regular initial data are dispersive? For example, we take the vacuum Maxwell equations - they will have the form (for the electric/magnetic field)

\begin{equation}
y_{xx}-c^{-2}y_{tt}=0.
\end{equation}

If we take $y(x,0)=\sin x$ and $\partial_t y(x,0)=(1/\epsilon)\sin x$ for the electric field and mutatis mutandis for the magnetic field, we obtain the electromagnetic wave - a dispersive solution.

Comment: Is there a wider context to this question? Maxwell's equations + boundary conditions definitely exhibit a **"non-statistical"** arrow of time (waves (photons) don't arrive from a notional spherical wave (photon) front generated at arbitrary distance, to then light a lamp; thereby generating a potential difference across the filament.). I'm afraid discussion of this point tends  to be overlooked/supressed in the majority of undergraduate physics textbooks. No one seems to question the statistical origin of all entropy. This is ultimately a research level question.